# JSONP 404 error angular

Tags: angularjs, web-services, jsonp

I wrote a web service -

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        String GetShift();
```

also i wrote a web app with javascript-

```
var response = $http.jsonp("http://localhost:53035/JuleSService.svc/");
            response.success(function (data) {
                alert("success");
            });

            response.error(function (data, status) {
                alert(data+"\r\n"+status);
            });
```

but it always goes into error with 404 code

Comment: what you get if you past http://localhost:53035/JuleSService.svc/ in your browser address bar ?

Comment: I get results ("Hello world" string)